# Next js <Image/> component doesnt overflow while making carousel like regular <img> tag

Tags: image, next.js, overflow, carousel

when I use one image inside the container carousel div the image occupies 100vw. But when I add multiple images inside the container it was supposed to be overflown but rather images get shrunk and act weird. I tried the same thing with regular HTML  tag and it works perfectly.

My question is how to make a carousel in Next js without using any library where on each slide there is only one Image covering 100% view width.

#code

```
<div className="embla" >
    <div className="embla__container">
        <Product_3
          src="/lifestyle/14.jpg"
          details="Discover the support you need to power through gaming marathons."
          name="CHAIRS"
        />         
    </div>
</div>
```

#CSS part

```
.embla {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.embla__container {
  display: flex;  
}
.embla__slide {
  width:100vw;
  height:10rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-shrink: none;
}
```

#Product_3 component

```
function Product_3({ src, name, details }) {
  return (
    <div className="product_3">
      <div className="product3_img">
        <Image src={src} layout="fill" />
      </div>
      <div className="product2_details">
        <h3 className="product2_name">{name}</h3>
        <div style={{fontSize:"2rem",color:"#999999",margin:"1rem 0 2rem 0"}}>
          {details}. 
        </div>
        <button className="learn_more product2_btn">Learn More {">"}</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```